# Connectedness of complex sphere

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X_{n}$ be a set 
$$
X_{n} = \{(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n})\in \mathbb{C}^{n}\,:\, x_{1}^{2}+ \cdots + x_{n}^{2} = 1\}. 
$$
For $n\geq 2$. 
Then $X_{n}$ is connected.

In the case of $\mathbb{R}$, it is just a sphere and one can show that it is path connected. However, over $\mathbb{C}$, I don't know how to prove it in an easy way. 
It is known that if $f(X_{1}, \dots, X_{n})\in \mathbb{C}[X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}]$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$, then its zero set in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ is connected with respect to usual topology on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, which is not easy to prove. Since $X_{n}$ is just a set defined by deg 2 equation, there might be easy way to prove this.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind: we can find a path from any point on the sphere to the point which satisfies $x_n = 0$ (for $n \geq 2$).  Inductively, this allows us to build a path from any point on the sphere to a point of the form $(x_1,0,\dots,0)$, and from there to $(1,0,\dots,0)$.

Comment: If you’re looking for a topological proof, you could show that the suspension of a topological space is path connected and that the suspension of $S^n$ is $S^{n+1}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: That should be an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically, $X_n(\mathbb{C})\subset\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is the intersection of $\sum x_i^2-\sum y_i^2=1$ with $\sum x_iy_i=0$.  This is an $S^{n-2}$-bundle over $y\in\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$ glued to an $S^{n-1}$ over the point $y=0$, so you can move around to  the limit point $y=0$ and use the connectedness of the fiber $S^{n-1}$ over the origin to get $X_n$ connected.